# Finding the the largest number in a list that its modulo with a given number is 0

Tags: python, recursion

I need to define a recursive function that receives a list of
non-negative integers `numbers`, and a positive integer `m`, and returns the largest number from the list that divides by m with no remainder.

I can't use loops or python's max function on a list.

I tried:

```
def find_max_mod(numbers, m):
    mx  = 1
    mxn = -1
    if len(numbers) == 1 and numbers[0] % m == 0:
        if mx > numbers[0]:
            mx = numbers[0]
            return mx
    if len(numbers) == 1 and numbers[0] % m != 0:
        return -1
    elif len(numbers) == 0:
        return -1
    elif numbers[-1] % m == 0 and numbers[-1] > mx:
        mx = numbers[-1]
    numbers = find_max_modulo(numbers[:-1], m)

    return mx
```

I can't figure how to save my largest number. Every recursive cycle it over-write on my `mx` number.

I think I have a problem with the base condition but it is the smallest problem.

Comment: why do you want to do it recursively?.. You do not have to.

Comment: I'm self learning and want to practice my recursive skills

Comment: There are better examples to use than this. Recursion is needed in some cases. But an important thing to learn about it is not to use it when you can do otherwise.

Comment: Since recursion is limited by default to a depth of ~999 in Python, I would say recursive is rarely the bulletproof solution in this particular language - iterative algorithms are the core of Python and converting from recursive to iterative is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
def find_max_mod(list_numbers, large_number, current_max_valid=0):
    if list_numbers[0] % large_number == 0:
        if current_max_valid < list_numbers[0]:
            current_max_valid = list_numbers[0]
    if len(list_numbers) > 1:
        return find_max_mod(list_numbers[1:], large_number, current_max_valid)
    return current_max_valid

list_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
print(find_max_mod(list_numbers, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close, you just need to modify the return statements

```
elif numbers[-1] % m == 0 and numbers[-1] > mx:
    mx = numbers[-1]
numbers = find_max_modulo(numbers[:-1], m)

return mx
```

to:

```
elif numbers[-1] % m == 0 and numbers[-1] > mx:
    return numbers[-1]
return find_max_modulo(numbers[:-1], m)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work on recursion, you should try to find exercises that fits your theme. For instance, Fibonnacci function for recursion is a good start.

Now as for your question, usually, for a recursive function, you need an if-statement that will stop your program from iterating. That condition may be a variable that will need to be passed thoughout the process as a **parameter**, or it might be a hard-coded condition to-be-met.

As you need to go through all the list, you need to think about a stop condition in the end of your list. You have multiple choices but I suggest you **pop** an item at each iteration : item that will be checked if it respects your requirements.

---

Now, you want to keep the largest number ?
You simply need to check if the item you received from **further computations** is a better fit than the one you have in your **current** recursive session : so that you can keep the one that best fits your needs.

Good luck. :)